# Flow (typo3) compared to yii

Tags: php, yii, frameworks, typo3-flow

I'm looking for any experiences people made using both of these frameworks.
Right now I'm using `Yii` for almost everything, but to give Flow a shot, I thought,
I ask people who worked with both of them. Can you give me any feedback and your experiences?

I found comparisons between `Zend` and `Yii`, `cakePHP` and `Yii` ... 
But nothing between `Yii` and `Flow`

Can you tell me something from your experience? Complexity, performance, security

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

I don't have tons of experience. Actually more with Yii but for my Job I'm learning Typo3 and have written an Extbase extension, which implements MVC technology. I have not done much with FLOW (that I know of).

A few remarks about my experience:

I find Yii to be much more intuitive. Once you've understood the basic concepts of the framework it is quite nice. When a problem occurs or I need to implement something, I can find the correct place to make changes very quickly.

I've worked quite a bit with the TYPO3 framework in the past and to be honest, I think it's a catastrophe. It works and many people are able to program in it quite successfully. However, for me many portions of it are a black-box that I do not understand. IMO TYPO3 makes things enormously complex that need not be so difficult. When I need to debug a TYPO3 problem I spend 60-80% percent of my time simply locating where or what is causing the problem.

However, EXTBASE seems to be a major step in the right direction. The concept and structure is quite similar to that what Yii uses. It even has a few features which I find nicer than Yii. For instance the pre- and post- processing of the Model takes care of the DB storage automatically. If you change values in the Model code you need not worry about saving things. Also, the conceptual model and the DB connection is more cleanly separated.

Also, the FLUID view/template tool is very nice. The coding syntax is very similar to HTML and quite intuitive. A Template can be written in a syntax that looks basically like a HTML document. The FLUID elements are also quite intuitive so that you know pretty much what's going on just by reading the code. It also makes the drudgery of complex display elements quite simple.

I still think Yii is a better product, but TYPO3 has made many good strides. If you can avoid the black-box of the TYPO3-Core things are OK.

Also, although TYPOSCRIPT seems to be getting less necessary it is still there and has caused me many headaches.

Comment: Please don’t mix up Flow and Extbase. Flow is a framework from which some components and concepts were backported/integrated into Typo3. But still, Typo3 does not include Flow, and even in a case like the template engine Fluid, which is present in both Typo3 and Flow, there are differences in the behaviour. (Apart from that I totally agree that Typo3 is complete und utter crap.)